# Template parameters for powershell script in Visual Studio project template?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, project-template, psake

I have a project template that contains a powershell script called BuildStandard.ps1.  Inside that script is the following excerpt:

```
Invoke-psake -buildFile $psakeScript `
            -parameters @{
                "solutionFile" = Resolve-Path("..\$SpecificSolutionName$.sln")
            }
```

When a new project is added using the template, I want the $SpecificSolutionName$ parameter to be replaced with, well, the solution name.  Only problem is that this content from the .vstemplate file isn't cutting it:

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="PsakeInstallTestBench.csproj" File="PsakeInstallTestBench.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">BuildStandard.ps1</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I've verified that if I replace `$SpecificSolutionName$` with `$safeprojectname$`, the parameter is replaced.  I'm beginning to wonder if `$SpecificSolutionName$` is available only for solution-level templates.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I think that you have to escape the $ with a back tick in your Resolve-Path call: Resolve-Path ..\`$SpecificSolutionName`$.sln   Also note that I have removed the parentheses.

Comment: Tried it, but no dice: the line in the new project still shows up verbatim: Resolve-Path(..\`$SpecificSolutionName`$.sln).  The backslash isn't playing a role here, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. My wrong: there should be a backslash.

Comment: Total SO confusion!  I believe both you and I *had* a backslash included in our comments before the first backtick, but it looks like SO is filtering it out.  In my .ps1 file, I do have the backslash included; I meant to inquire whether the presence of the backslash in the .ps1 file before the backtick might cause the $ to be escaped.